# MySQL 8.0.30+ - Check if a POINT() is inside a POLYGON() using SRID 4326

Tags: mysql, geospatial, mysql-8.0, srid

I'm using MySQL 8.0.30 which has fixed a major known issue related to SPATIAL indexes.

I've modified a POINT() column to transform it to SRID 4326.

**Before, I had the following query returning 20+ rows:**

```
SELECT r.id
FROM record r
WHERE ST_CONTAINS(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((-74.5 40.5, -73 40.5, -73 39.5, -74.5 39.6, -74.5 40.5))'), r.location);
```

The `location` column had a SPATIAL index that was not used by the MySQL engine as the SRID was missing on this column. The query was working but slow.

**After, I added an SRID 4326 definition on that column, made sure I had no NULL entries and added a SPATIAL index:**

```
mysql> describe record;
+-------------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field             | Type             | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+-------------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| id                | int unsigned     | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment                                    |
| location          | point            | NO   | MUL | NOT NULL          |                             
+-------------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
```

and

```
mysql> show indexes from record;
+--------------+------------+-----------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| Table        | Non_unique | Key_name                    | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Visible | Expression |
+--------------+------------+-----------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| record       |          1 | my_spatial                  |            1 | location    | A         |       14351 |       32 |   NULL |      | SPATIAL    |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
+--------------+------------+-----------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
```

**Here is the new query, forcing the use of SRID 4326:**

```
SELECT r.id
FROM record r
WHERE ST_CONTAINS(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((-74.5 40.5, -73 40.5, -73 39.5, -74.5 39.6, 
-74.5 40.5))', 4326), r.location);
```

**I am not getting any error, however the previous query was returning 20+ rows and I'm now getting 0.**

I checked both SRID and they look good to me:

```
mysql> select ST_SRID(location) from record limit 1;
+--------------------+
| ST_SRID(location) |
+--------------------+
|               4326 |
+--------------------+

mysql> select ST_SRID(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((-74.5 40.5, -73 40.5, -73 39.5, -74.5 39.6, -74.5 40.5))', 4326));
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ST_SRID(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((-74.5 40.5, -73 40.5, -73 39.5, -74.5 39.6, -74.5 40.5))', 4326)) |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                                                4326 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Am I doing something the wrong way?

Comment: What SQL statement did you use to update the existing records in the `record` table to the new SRID 4326?.

Comment: @wchiquito I used this `UPDATE record SET location2 = ST_SRID(location, 4326);` - Which worked well. I discovered today the reason for the issue was this statement inverted lat/lng and I had to adjust the Polygon coordinate. I will post a detailed, step-by-step answer next week :) Thank you!

Comment: Possibly `UPDATE record SET location2 = ST_GeomFromWKB(ST_AsBinary(location), 4326);` statement would have worked without adjusting Polygon coordinate. Here is a good [compendium](https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/?tag=spatial) of articles related to the topic.

Comment: Could we see the value of one of the POINTs?